# What does 'this' keyword mean in a method parameter?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, html-helper

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    // Summary:
    //     Represents support for HTML in an application.
    public static class FormExtensions
    {
        public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName);
...
    }
}
```

I have noticed that 'this' object in front of the first parameter in BeginForm method doesn't seem to be accepted as a parameter. Looks like in real BeginForm methods functions as:

```
BeginForm(string actionName, string controllerName);
```

omitting the first parameter. But it actually receives that first parameter somehow in a hidden way.
Can you please explain me how this structure works. I actually exploring MVC 4 internet Sample. 
Thank you.

Comment: This is an extension method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Comment: THank you, I will go through this.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is how extension methods works in C#. The Extension Methods feature allowing you to extend existing types with custom methods.
The `this [TypeName]` keyword in the context of method's parameters is the `type` that you want to extend with your custom  methods, the `this` is used as a prefix, in your case, `HtmlHelper` is the `type` to extend and `BeginForm` is the method which should extend it.

Take a look at this simple extention method for the `string` type:

```
public static bool BiggerThan(this string theString, int minChars)
{
  return (theString.Length > minChars);
}
```

You can easily use it on `string` object:

```
var isBigger = "my string is bigger than 20 chars?".BiggerThan(20);
```

References:

- Well-documented reference would be: [How to: Implement and Call a
  Custom Extension Method (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311042.aspx)
- More particular reference about Extention Methods in ASP.NET MVC would be:
  [How To Create Custom MVC Extension Methods](http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2010/10/09/how-to-create-custom-mvc-extension-methods.aspx)

Comment: @YairNevet Does the method need to be declared as `static` for this to work?

Comment: @thatWiseGuy yes, it is

Answer (score 3):

Extension Methods:

A "bolt on" way to extend an existing type. They allow you to extend an existing type with new functionality, without having to sub-class or recompile the old type. For instance, you might like to know whether a certain string was a number or not. Or you might want to have the Show() Hide() functionality in ASP.net WebForms for controls.

For Example:

```
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static void Show(this Control subject)
    {
        subject.Visible = true;
    }
    public static bool IsNumeric(this string s)
    {
        float output;
        return float.TryParse(s, out output);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
For futher information you can see the MSDN documentation at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx which was kindly linked by @aush.

I enjoyed reading "C# In Depth" regarding Extension Methods. There is an excerpt available here:
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9781935182474/extension-methods/ch10lev1sec3

You can of course buy the book online or you can just do some research into how it all works under the hood using Google.