# In C# What does "this" declared before parameter type of a method declaration mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm reading the EntityFramework Core [Code on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/03bcb5122e3f577a84498545fcf130ba79a3d987/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) and I don't understand what this([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this)) is used for below:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddDbContext<TContext>(
        [NotNull] this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
        ServiceLifetime contextLifetime)
        where TContext : DbContext
        => AddDbContext<TContext>(serviceCollection, (Action<IServiceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder>)null, contextLifetime);
```

Comment: "what is an extension method?"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035330/what-does-this-keyword-mean-in-a-method-parameter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: Geez, that was fast. Ok I'll mark as duplicate now and then read all these.

Comment: @user5389726598465 it's already marked :)